# Users are indexed as sitemaps by Google Search

Tags: feature-request, status-review, users

Is it possible to put up proper sitemaps for Google search, instead of some random users?

[image]

Comment: To tell you the truth, I have no idea; I'd have to ask.

Comment: not reproducible anymore. Neither on Computational Sciense SE, nor on other SE websites I tried, including the ones with the lowest number of users (subject to more border conditions).

Comment: @AntonMenshov Google it: "computational science stack exchange" and it shows your account! lol...

Comment: @AloneProgrammer was not the case a year ago. Will see what can be done. THanks!

Comment: I'll forward this bug report to the relevant developer team to see if this is still occurring (and whether there's anything we can do, if so).